# Automate deployment of web application on IIS via ASP.NET web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

How can I deploy an web application on IIS via ASP.NET web application?

So instead of creating virtual directory, converting it to a application, etc I could just automate deployment via a web application?

how do I do that?

EDIT: no i do not want to deploy my application via visual studio, instead I want my web application itself to deploy a web application.

Example I use webapplication1, using webapplication1, I login to my control panel, I then setup the application to deploy within webapplication1, then I click deploy, and it deploys webapplicationX, webapplicationY, webapplicationN etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five types of setup and deployment projects in VS.NET, but three are of significant importance that are "SetUp Project", "Web Setup Project" and "Merge Module Project".

[Go to this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx)

Comment: not what I want to do, I want to deploy a web application from within a web application. See Edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a new Visual Studio project of type "Setup and Deployment", and use the "Web Setup" type.
This will create an .msi installer that will automatically create the web app for you within IIS.

Comment: not what I want to do, I want to deploy a web application from within a web application. See Edit above.